# What is the difference between the Disk Cache and TMP storage?

Tags: http, caching, local-storage, storage, disk

What are the purposes of using the Disk Cache and TMP storage?

I found this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) so we can consider Disk Cache is a local cache but what is the difference between them?